# IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to subtract two positions of different ArrayLists and save the result in another ArrayList but i'm getting the IndexOutOfBoundsException error. I understand how works this error and what it means. 
The problem is that when I run my code with the debugger it works fine, but if I run it normally it gives me the error.

[Here I declare the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEyGV.png)

[Here is the for loop code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP47u.png)

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTx58.png)

Both Lists, "accels" and "gravs" have the same size 252. I don't understand why step by step it works and all continous no.

Comment: Please paste codes and logs as texts.

Comment: If you could post the relevant code where you face the problem, people might be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < accels.size() && i < gravs.size(); i++) {

}
```

Comment: It works thank you. But can you explain me why i have to consider both lists sizes? I understand that, if are same, only taking one of them is enough to now the number of steps

Comment: Apparently they are not the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Try the loop without checking `<=` for your iteration. i.e (`i < accels.size()`)